# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Tags: django, django-managers

hi i create a custom manager class called usermanager in monage.py
to customise my login template for 2 types of user admin,entrepreneur

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
import sys
def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oasisconsuting.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The given email must be set")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

after running the makemigration (it's ok)
when i run the migration code we receive the errors
what is the wrong in this code to show me this errors :

```
C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/business/oasisconsuting/manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/business/oasisconsuting/manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 
2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", 
line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 107, 
in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in 
get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in 
check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in 
__getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\business\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in 
_setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not 
configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

should i keep this code or i should change it
how i can

- call setting.configure()
  or

  - define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    to fix my problem or there is another method to do

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have gotten an answer to your question, but let me still post the answer maybe for other people.

I ran into the same error, and I was able to solve it by calling the settings.configure() as the error message throws.
First, you have to import your settings before you can configure it.

**Like this**

```
from django.conf import settings
```

***and then call it,***

```
settings.configure()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see some issues:

1. In main() function I think there is a bug in last line, Is not having one indent more than it should?. Perhaps the code should be:

   ```
   def main():
       os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oasisconsuting.settings')
       try:
           from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
       except ImportError as exc:
           raise ImportError(
               "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
               "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
               "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
           ) from exc
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
   ```
2. Do you really need to do a script? Best practice with Django will be to create a custom django-admin commands, you can check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. The issue seems to be totally with this line `from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager` , and rightfully so. We have not configured the the django settings yet and we are making this call from within a module of djang.

Try moving the line `from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager` and all other such imports, below `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oasisconsuting.settings')` and it should resolve the issue.

In simpler words, just put this line at the very top of your file:

`import os; os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")`

Answer (score 0):

This error is simply because of not telling Django which setting file it should use. there is 3 different ways to handle it...

1- define a environment variable in the operating system([link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)).

2- if you are using a virtual environment; set a new environment variable in activate.bat

```
 set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=oasisconsuting.settings"
```

3- (the way you did!)in each python file; write the command which defines that environment variable.

```
 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'oasisconsuting.settings')
```

but if use this method it is really important where you are putting that command(in the second and definitely first case we don't care at all!).
so you should take care of not using django before that command.